# border-radius and box-shadow not working in IE7, i'm using PIE.htc file.

Tags: css

Border-radius and box-shadow are not working in IE7. I'm using the PIE.htc file. The path is correct, I checked it. Don't know where it's going wrong. I used it before too and it was working then.
Don't know the reason this time.

```
.box-shadow-outer { 
float: left; font-size: 40px;
border: 2px solid #c4c4c4;
padding: 80px 0;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
background: #e4e4e4;
behavior: url(../../Content/Css/PIE.htc); 
}
```

Comment: .box-shadow-outer
{
 float: left;
 font-size: 40px;
 border: 2px solid #c4c4c4;
 padding: 80px 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 500px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
 -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
 box-shadow: #666 0px 0px 10px;
 background: #e4e4e4;
 behavior: url(../../Content/Css/PIE.htc);
}

Answer (score 4):

`float: left;` is creating problems.

You can solve it by 2 ways:

1. Remove `float: left;`
2. add this style:

   ```
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
   ```